# 404 Error setting up subdomain with nginx, unicorn, rails

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, vps, unicorn

I have a VPS and recently moved my server setup from apache/passenger to nginx/unicorn and added a staging server. If I hit the server directly, http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx, my app comes up no problem. If, however, I hit it with the staging subdomain, http://staging.myurl.com, I get a 404. I suspect there is an issue with unicorn, but I cannot figure it out.

Here is what I have:

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/codemarks

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.blog.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name staging.codemarks.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/codemarks/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Then in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx staging.codemarks.com   staging
```

I have one DNS record for the site and added an A record to point staging to my new IP. Also, I have inspected /var/log/nginx/access.log and the direct (successful) request gets logged, but hitting it with staging.codemarks.com yeilds

```
216.21.198.16 - - [26/Dec/2012:14:41:07 -0500] "GET /codemarks HTTP/1.1" 404 446 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/537.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1337.0 Safari/537.20
```

I am new to using unicorn, so I'm not sure what am I missing. Since the direct hit is successful, I suspect either a DNS problem or some missing domain-specific unicorn setting, but I am hitting a wall. Thanks in advance for help!

*UPDATE*

The /tmp/unicorn.blog.sock seems out of place because I stole part of a railscast that had it. It should work, though, since I'm passing this in as my unicorn config:

config/unicorn.rb

```
root = "/home/deployer/apps/codemarks/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.blog.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
```

I set up my unicorn.blog.sock by (blindly and unknowingly) running:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f unicorn_blog defaults
```